# Error for every epoch in training a ANN

Tags: matlab, neural-network

Hi everyone and thank you for taking time to read this.
I have the following code to train a neural network:

```
P = [-1 2 0.5 3];
T1 = 1;
T2 = 2;
T3 = 1.5;
net = newff([-1 3;-1 3;-1 3;-1 3],[2 1],{'logsig' 'logsig'},'traingd');
net.trainParam.epochs = 50;
net.trainParam.lr = 0.6;
%now start to train for the first 50 epochs
[net,Y,E,Pf,Af,tr] = train(net,P',T1)
```

I want to have error for every epoch. I trained my network for 50 epochs and at the end it gives me the final error but I want but I want all of the errors!

Comment: t1, t2 and t3 are just some target values with respect to the input p.

Answer (score 0):

If you know you are going to train for 50 epochs you can set up an array and record the error for each one.